# Using acr_values="idp:Google" with Xmarin's IdentityModel.OidcClient does not Skip login page on identityserver4

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am using the [sample code](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/blob/master/AndroidClientChromeCustomTabs/AndroidClientChromeCustomTabs/MainActivity.cs) for xamarin oidcclient to authenticate users,

I want to skip login page if user chooses an external provider, I was able to do that in sample code by adding extras parameter acr_values:

```
var result = await _oidcClient.LoginAsync(extraParameters: new { acr_values="idp:Google" });
```

and it worked, but not with me implementation of identityserer4, my client config is:

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    RequireConsent=false,
                    AccessTokenType=AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser=true,

                    ClientSecrets = {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "http://192.168.1.6.nip.io:13013/Home/", "io.identitymodel.native://TrainAppCallback" },

                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://192.168.1.6.nip.io:13013/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "Advancio.TrainApp.WebApi"
                    },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                    RequirePkce = true
                }
```

am I missing some configuration on idsrv? because the only difference in my client code is the authorization endpoint (instead of https://demo.identityserver.io I use my local implementation of idsrv).

**the authorization request log is :**

```
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "mvc",
        "ClientName": "MVC Client",
        "RedirectUri": "io.identitymodel.native://TrainAppCallback",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://192.168.5.165.nip.io:13013/Home/",
          "io.identitymodel.native://TrainAppCallback",
          "io.identitymodel.native://callback"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "fragment",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile Advancio.TrainApp.WebApi",
        "Nonce": "9723a6643f38b51711400677cb30db73c4c0dda2de20c7ccebf71a06937be32f943d29e04763571337cda90391bb994afaf1d3188992955f045b16825133771b",
        "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": [
          "idp:Google"
        ],
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "mvc",
          "response_type": "code id_token",
          "scope": "openid profile Advancio.TrainApp.WebApi",
          "redirect_uri": "io.identitymodel.native://TrainAppCallback",
          "nonce": "9723a6643f38b51711400677cb30db73c4c0dda2de20c7ccebf71a06937be32f943d29e04763571337cda90391bb994afaf1d3188992955f045b16825133771b",
          "code_challenge": "Fpdz7OYUZPyE47Qvc3efwg8-UuAmLhiOQmCAYMqoSZw",
          "code_challenge_method": "S256",
          "acr_values": "idp:Google"
        }
      }
```

Comment: This assumes you have the Google authentication middleware with an AuthenticationScheme of `Google` registered in your pipeline. Also check the server logs.

Comment: I updated my question to include server log of the authorization request, the AuthenticationScheme is same as the name in acr_values, I have checked the IdentityServer4.Demo to find any thing diffrent at my end with no luck, I am wondering if I should implement the redirection somewhere like UserService ?!

Comment: by exploring the demo project, I found that I had to implement this behavior my self, thanks to IdentityServer4 samples I found the sample project I needed.